# How to make UIBarButtonItem invisible but working?

Tags: ios

I have this method which returns UIBarButtonItem, I want invisible button but working when someone click over that,,,,,

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {

UIBarButtonItem *barbuttonitem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bacbbutton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:)];


return barbuttonitem;
}
```

How can I make this button invisible, but whenever use click that corner or navigationbar, the button get work, but visibility should be hidden...

Comment: There is no method like setAlpha for BarButtonItem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bacbbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.alpha = 0.3;
UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

Comment: Reduce your alpha value such that which suits to your requirement

Comment: Dear its behaving like hidden, it is calling the button leftSideMenuButtonPressed,

Comment: vary your alpha in between to 0 and 1 and check like 0.1,0.4,0.5... so on

Comment: there is no need to set btn.alpha bcz it button type custom and also you can do it with [UIImage imageNamed:@""]

Answer (score 1):

Setting the button to be `hidden` will mean that it can't be tapped. You just want to set it to be transparent. You need to do this by creating a bar button item with a custom view and setting the view `alpha` to zero. The custom view will be a `UIButton`.

Comment: @Veer Have you **read** the answer? Wain isn't suggesting that there is one.

Comment: @Wain nevermind... Still, to OP: thinking and making some effort solving one's problems isn't prohibited, is it.

Comment: @H2CO3, When I gave comment, there was code, then was edited.